# Shortcut target maximum character exceeded

Tags: windows-7, windows, shortcuts, environment-variables

Is there a way to manage the limit of character in target in shorcuts?

I need to add more commands in a target (to set environment variables) and I can't!

Comment: Did you find a direct solution without using a bat file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a batch file that sets the required environment variables and starts the program afterwards. You can then use the batch file as the target of your shortcut.

Comment: Thanks @Joey , can you give an example?